# Not able to login to ExpressionEngine 2 Control Panel

Tags: control-panel, login, authentication, authenticate

When i try to login, i am justing hanging at a white screen.
The URL in the browser is, http://myintranetsite.com/system/index.php?/cp/login/authenticate

It stays at that url and never lets me get logged in.
After quite some time it times out and i get a Fatal Error.

Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in c:\path...\root\system\expressionengine\libraries\El_pings.php on line 244

FYI, I am running the most up to date version of EE2 on a Windows Server

Answer (score 0):

This is the library file that EE uses to phone home. It most likely means your installation can't phone home to Ellis Labs correctly. Your example URL ... `http://myintranetsite.com` make it sound like an internal tool, and not a public facing site. Is the network this site is on connected to the internet?